# Cartesian to Polar Transformation Bug?

Tags: differential-equations

I was trying to do this problem with Mathematica [*Equating Coefficients of Cos and Sin*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2995287/equating-coefficients-of-cos-and-sin)

We have

```
    TransformedField[
     "Cartesian" -> "Polar", {x/2 - y - 1/2 (x^3 + y^2 x), 
      x + y/2 - 1/2 (y^3 + x^2 y)}, {x, y} -> {r, \[Theta]}] // Simplify
```

The result is

$$\left\{\frac{1}{2} \left(r-r^3\right),r\right\}$$

However, the book (well respected) and one of the answers match, but that is different than the above.

$$\left\{\frac{1}{2} \left(r-r^3\right),1\right\}$$

Notice that $\theta' = r$ according to Mathematica, but it is equal to one when this is done by hand. It seems that Mathematica is not dividing by $r$ in the last step. Is this a bug in Mathematica? Is there a way to check that?

Comment: Please do not use the [tag:bugs] tag when posting your own questions. Do add this tag to others' questions once you have independently verified that there is indeed a bug. Please see the tag description.

Comment: @Szabolcs: Thanks for that clarification.

Comment: @Szabolcs: Doesn't that vector plot confirm that this is a radially inward spiral? In other words, the result should be $1$? It is worth noting that I have used this approach on dozens of problems and have not had this issue before until now..

Comment: What I said above was indeed wrong, but the result still checks out. If we put `y -> 0`, we get `{x/2 - x^3/2, x}`.  This is the case when $\theta=0$ and $x=r$, and the basis vectors are identical, so Mathematica's result seems correct.

Comment: If you look the answer (this agrees with hand calculations) by JJacquelin at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2995287/equating-coefficients-of-cos-and-sin, this shows the discrepancy - so I am confused by Mathematica's result.